# Seach logfile with current date without using double qoutes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I'm trying use grep command to search a large log file for lines starting with current date through server automation application and the date format written in log file is 'Month Date'.

The limitation is we cannot use double quotes in the command while running it from this application.

I tried to grep the file with below command, but it's not working since it is replacing the date variable with space in between month and date, and due to that grep is treating month as the word to search and date as file.

```
grep `date +%b\ %d` filename
```

Can someone help me fix this, so the date variable gets replaced with single quotes, for example `Oct 30`, so grep can treat it as single word for searching?

Please note we cannot use double quotes in entire command.

Comment: That's an extremely odd limitation for a shell script, which relies heavily on proper quoting to work correctly.

Comment: Why can't you use double quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
grep `date +%b[[:space:]]%d` filename
```

or

```
grep $(date +%b[[:space:]]%d) filename
```

Comment: Nice though this will get globbed if a file matching that date string exists (with any whitespace in the center position.

Comment: The problem isn't the whitespace in the pattern; it's the whitespace in the *result* which breaks `grep`.

Comment: It works fine because there appears no whitespace. See: `echo  $(date +%b[[:space:]]%d)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep `date +%b.*%d` largelog.log
```

This works unless you have 30 after Oct anywhere in your log line.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `IFS` to a character that doesn't appear in the output of `date`; a colon should suffice. Localize the change in a subshell to avoid needing to restore the previous value.

```
(IFS=:; grep $(date +%b\ %d) file)
```